# Add html tags to every sentence in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to modify my div with text using jQuery / javascript.
Basically script should look for each "." and "!" and "?" and wrap each sentences into dd tag

So at the moment my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="test">Some text here. Another text there! And another thing here. Additional stuff? Random text.</div>
```

At the end it should looks like this:

```
<div class="test">
<ul>
   <dd>Some text here</dd> 
   <dd>Another text there</dd>
   <dd>And another thing here</dd>
   <dd>Additional stuff</dd>
   <dd>Random text</dd>
</ul>
</div>
```

help -_-

Comment: Use split and map like `string.split(/\.\s+/g).map(x => "<dd>" +x +"</dd>")`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful. I solved my problem with this (works for me):

jQuery('div.test').each(function() {
    var sentences = jQuery(this).text().split(/\.|\?|\!\s+/g),
    $wrapper = jQuery(this).empty();

    jQuery.each(sentences, function(_, sentence) {
       jQuery('<dd>', {text: sentence}).appendTo($wrapper).wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
    });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting,thanks

```js
var data = $('.test').text().split(/[.\!?]/) // split string based on '.','!','?'
var str='<ul>'
for(d in data)
 str+='<dd>'+data[d]+'</dd>'
str+='</ul>'
$('.test').html(str)                        //Attach to div test
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Some text here. Another text there! And another thing here. Additional stuff? Random text.</div>
```